# Legend outside of plot is not showing when exported with pdf()

Tags: r, plot, legend

My problem is basically the same as this question here: [R legend outside of graph not showing in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494344/r-legend-outside-of-graph-not-showing-in-pdf)

However, none of the answers to this question solved the problem. So, in the hope of finding an answer 5 years later, I am asking the question again.

My code is the following:

```
for(i in 1:20){    
  pdf(paste0("Plot_BOTH_cM-Mb_CHR", i, ".pdf"), width = 10, height = 8) 
  par(mar = c(5,5,5,10), xpd = T)
  plot(cm_r10 ~ mb, data = subset(recomb_match[[i]], recomb_match[[i]][,"snp_both"]=="1_1"),
       las = 1, main = paste("chromosome",i, sep = " "),
       xlab = "Mb", ylab = "cM", ylim = c(0,120))
  points(cm_m10 ~ mb, data = subset(recomb_match[[i]], recomb_match[[i]][,"snp_both"]=="1_1"), 
  col = "red")
  legend("topright", inset=c(-0.81,-0.08), col = c("black","red"), 
         legend = c("RheMac10 (old)","Mmul_10 (new)"), bty="n", pch = 19,
         y.intersp=0.2, x.intersp = 0.2, xpd = T)
  dev.off()
}
```

When I export the plot manually in RStudio, the legend is displayed in the pdf file. When I try to export it via the command line using the pdf() function, the legend is not displayed. Since I have to create 20 plots, I would appreciate to automate the process.

Comment: Your `inset=` appears to be off, try without first then adapt step by step. Forget RStudio preview window if you use the `pdf` device, only look at one `.pdf`. On Linux the view refreshes when created new, not sure which OS you use.

Comment: That did the trick - Thanks a lot! I didn't expect the inset coordinates to differ so much between the manually and automatically exported PDFs. For the record, I'm using R on a Linux remote server.

Comment: Great, maybe with `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` you can open the .pdf, using `xdg-open foo.pdf`, not tested though.